# Create HttpServletResponse object in Zuul custom filter

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-zuul

I have a Zuul custom filter of type `PRE_TYPE`.
When I receive the request I want to prevent its routing and instead send a response, in this case a SOAP message, since I am simulating a web service response.
My custom filter:

```
  @Component
public class CustomFilter extends ZuulFilter {
    private ThreadLocal<byte[]> buffers;

    @Override
    public boolean shouldFilter() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Object run() {
        RequestContext ctx = getCurrentContext();
        ctx.unset();
        String s= "<soap:Envelope xmlns:......</soap:Envelope>";


 }

    @Override
    public String filterType() {
        return FilterConstants.PRE_TYPE;
    }

    @Override
    public int filterOrder() {
        return 0;
        }
}
```

I need to create a HttpServletResponse and fill it with my response and write it to the output stream, so the client receives that response.
How can I create the servletresponse object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```java
@Override
public Object run() {
    RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
    ctx.setSendZuulResponse(false);
    ctx.setResponseBody("<soap:Envelope xmlns:......</soap:Envelope>");
    ctx.setResponseStatusCode(...);
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Will this set `Content-Length` properly?